# Connecting Presto to Kafka does fails - Catalog 'kafka' does not exist

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, presto

I tried to do something similar as the instructions outlined [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html#step-2-load-data). Just in my case I wanted to start presto and kafka in docker using docker-compose.

So my docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '2'  
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
    networks:
      - shared
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092,LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - shared
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "8089:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka1:19092"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka1"
    networks:
      - shared
  presto:
    image: ahanaio/prestodb-sandbox:latest
    ports:
      - 8087:8080
    volumes:
    - ./presto/kafka.properties:/etc/catalog/kafka.properties
    networks:
      - shared
networks:
  shared:
    name: kappa-playground
    driver: bridge
```

The mounted file kafka.properties has the following content:

```
connector.name=kafka
kafka.nodes=kafka1:19092
kafka.table-names=example_topic
```

I ensure kafka has the topic create with the following little script:

```
# requires kafka-python
from kafka import KafkaClient
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic

client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:29092')
admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092", 
    client_id='setup'
)
future = client.cluster.request_update()
client.poll(future=future)
metadata = client.cluster
topics = metadata.topics()
if(len(topics) > 0 ):
    print("topics: " + " ".join(topics))
else:
    print("no topics exist yet")
if("example_topic" not in topics):
    topic_list = []
    topic_list.append(NewTopic(name="example_topic", num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1))
    admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

I can verify the topic "example_topic" exists with kafdrop.

Now I try to verify that presto can ready the topics from kafka like this:

```
presto --server=localhost:8087 --catalog kafka --schema default
presto:default> SHOW TABLES;
```

Which shows the following error:

```
Query 20220622_080948_00005_t2k7a failed: line 1:1: Catalog 'kafka' does not exist
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. The kafka.properties file was mounted to the wrong path.

It should rather be:

```
  presto:
    image: ahanaio/prestodb-sandbox:latest
    ports:
      - 8087:8080
    volumes:
    - ./presto/kafka.properties:/opt/presto-server/etc/catalog/kafka.properties
    networks:
      - shared
```